# Apache HttpComponents request.get.excute is not returning correct HTML source code

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-httpcomponents

I am using Apache HttpComponents with 150 threads to download HTML source code for roughly 5000 different URLs.

The URL's are contained in a `LinkedBlockingQueue` and the `SourceGetterThreads` take from the queue when possible. A thread will then attempt to download the source code using `EntityUtils.toString(HttpClient.execute().getEntity)`. The string representation of the HTML source code is then put on another `LinkedBlockingQueue` where I have a further 10 threads ready to peform useful work on the source code they take from the second queue.

My problem lies in that I have noticed errors in the work being peformed on the source code. I am using `Matcher` to match specific patterns and record the patterns found. However sometimes the source code is incorrect and does not match the URL (i.e the source code saved in my java memory is not the same as the source code when viewed in Chrome or FireFox). This is seemingly random and thus sometimes the source code is correct and sometimes it is not.

Does anybody know why this is?

Comment: You have not provided anywhere near the amount of detail we'll need to answer this.

Comment: I tried to keep it abstract and refrain from proving too much such that tl;dr. I appreciate the negative though instead of asking for more information.

Comment: I have added more detail, any help you could provide would be most welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the sites you're trying to fetch pages from perform some kind of request filtering based on request headers, like `User-Agent`. So they can simply return different content based on the analysis result.There are many reasons to do so:

1. Provide search robots with appropriate info
2. Deny web-crawlers from fetching site's content
3. Recognize mobile devices and supply their user with different HTML/CSS/JS
4. If you're querying the same site intensively some kind of DOS-attack protection may be triggered, causing a stub error page being returned instead of a regular content

If you want to get the same content as in browser, then the most basic recommendation for your client is to behave like a browser:

1. Always provide `User-Agent` header
2. Follow HTTP redirect (HTTP codes 302,303)
3. Maintain cookies and authentication routines if required
4. Be ready to support HTTPS scheme

Without the source code you're trying to run it's hard to say more, but Apache HTTP Client you're using is definitely capable to do all these things. Here's, for example, how to set `User-Agent` value:

```
String url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=httpClient";
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
request.addHeader("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

Comment: sorry to be a pain, but do you know how I would go about setting the user-agent header?

Comment: No problem) Please refer to the updated answer for the code sample. It may depend on the Http Client version, though. (my code uses 4.X)